# How to increase server timeout in Apisauce

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios, apisauce

I have a request that exceeds 30 seconds, but it can be completed after 30 seconds. How can I increase the server timeout?

I increased the timeout on the config file but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Default timeouts can be applied too:

```
const api = create({ baseURL: '...', timeout: 30000 }) // 30 seconds
```

If you can check the documentation of this library it will answer most of your questions. https://github.com/infinitered/apisauce

Comment: The timeout here sets the connection timeout.